# pdfMake: "Uncaught File [font.tff]" appears to prevent function from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, pdfmake

I've never used [pdfMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) before and I'm trying to convert some text into a PDF via a button click. I'm importing pdfMake into `index.js` so I'm not sure if pdfMake itself is working or not.

I'm getting a console error: `Uncaught File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system` and I believe it's preventing the function from running. I tweaked my index.js file a bit (see commented code), but still nothing. Any thoughts on this one?

### index.js:

```
import 'jquery';
import './SiteAssets/styles/RecruitmentTracking.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import './SiteAssets/scripts/printPDF.js';

import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';

import 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js';
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

// import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
// pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
// require('imports-loader?this=>window!pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');

console.log('this is index.js');
```

### printPDF.js:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// import { pdfMake } from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js';

console.log('this is printPDF')

function _myFunc() {

    var docDefinition = {
        content: [
            'First paragraph',
            'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
    };

    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('test.pdf');
    console.log(docDefinition.content)

}

$("#pdf-trigger").on("click", _myFunc)

console.log(_myFunc)
```

#### index.html:

```
<!-- Button trigger PDF -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
          id="pdf-trigger" data-toggle="" 
          data-target="#pdfprint">PDF Print</button>
```

#### console.log:

```
log.js?1afd:24 - [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

printPDF.js?40b7:5 - this is printPDF

pdfmake.min.js?be6c:8 - Uncaught File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system

client?56b6:85 - [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

Comment: $("#pdf-trigger").on("click", _myFunc) -> pass the definition not his return

Comment: Thanks, I just made the change. But onClick I'm now seeing the "Uncaught File" error in the console. I've been browsing SO and GH and some people have found solutions for the same problem but nothing's worked for me (yet). Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

As per GH user [RizkiDPrast's suggestion](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/910), I went into `vfs_fonts.js` and edited the top line from: `this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {` to: `pdfMake = pdfMake || {}; pdfMake.vfs = {`